# Android, flavors, flavors, flavors and flavors

Tags: android, xml, gradle, android-productflavors

So as you can see from the title I have a problem with duplicates.

You are not allowed to have the same file defined in your flavor and your main directory. But you are allowed doing this with xml resources.

So how does it works? For example, my build variant is **RedStagingDebug**, and I have the *main_menu_layout.xml* defined in 3 folders:

- main/res/layout/main_menu.xml
- red/res/layout/main_menu.xml
- debug/res/layout/main_menu.xml

Which file will be used in my build and why?

Answer (score 0):

> Which file will be used in my build

`debug/res/layout/main_menu.xml` will be used

> and why?

Because [the documentation says so](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging). Build types trump product flavors, which trump `main`, which trump resources from library projects.

Comment: But in my example I have several build types, aren't those same priority and should rase an exception?

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman: "But in my example I have several build types" -- that is not covered in your question, where you only cite a `debug` build type. `red` is (presumably) a product flavor, and `main` is `main`. "aren't those same priority and should rase an exception?" -- no, because you can only build one build type at a time. In your case, you are requesting the `debug` build type.